# PHP Form not displaying Error Messages on the form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fix our website that someone else created and I'm trying to display validation errors on the form itself. I've tried searching high and low and can't get it to work. For example, if the phone number is less than 2 characters, it will display the error message on the form, not as a popup. If everything passes validation, the form will be e-mailed.

Right now, the problem is if someone enters information that doesn't pass validation, there are no errors displayed and the customer thinks they sent us an e-mail.

Here's the contact form:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include("captcha.php");
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();

if($_POST){
    include("contact_process.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html hola_ext_inject="disabled">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Mobile Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <!-- Put favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s).png in the images folder -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <!-- CSS StyleSheets -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/responsive.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/skins/default.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- site preloader start -->
    <div class="page-loader">
    =
    <div class="loader-in"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- site preloader end -->
    <div class="pageWrapper">
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <div id="headWrapper" class="clearfix">
    <!-- top bar start -->
    <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell-5">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- top bar end -->
    <!-- Logo, global navigation menu and search start -->
    <header class="top-head">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="logo cell-3">
    <a href="/index.html"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-logo-headline">
    <headline>
    Test
    </headline>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-5 top-menu">
    <!-- top navigation menu start -->
    <nav class="top-nav">
    </nav>
    <!-- top navigation menu end -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>

        </div>
        <!-- Header End -->

        <!-- Content Start -->
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div class="page-title title-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell-12">
                            <h1 class="fx" data-animate="fadeInLeft">Contact <span>us</span></h1>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="padd-top-50">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell-7 contact-form fx" data-animate="fadeInLeft" id="contact">
                            <h3 class="block-head"></h3>
                            <div id="message" style="display: none;">

                                <p class="congrats">Thank You!</p>
                                <p class="congratsTxt">Your Message was successfully Sent , please click the link below to go to home page.</p>
                                <div><a href="/index.html" class="btn btn-large main-bg">Go to home page</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <form class="form-signin cform" method="post" action="contact_process.php" id="cform" autocomplete="on">
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <label>First name<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="form-input">
                                    <label>Company name<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <label>Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <label>Phone<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <label>Message<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="7" id="messageTxt" spellcheck="true" required></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-input">
                              <h4 class="block-head">Direct Message To: </h4>
                                <select name="to">
                                <option value="0">Sales (product information, price inquiries, quotes)</option>
                                <option value="1">Tech Support (troubleshoot hardware or software issues)</option>
                                <option value="2">Accounting (billing questions, A/P, A/R)</option>
                                <option value="3">Engineering (application engineering support)</option>
                                <option value="4">Marketing (contact the Marketing department)</option>
                                <option value="5">Order Inquiry (check existing order status)</option>
                                </select> </div>

                                <div  class="form-input">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="cell-12 margin-bottom-20"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']; ?>" id='captchaimg' ></div>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="hidCap" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['code']; ?>" data-error="The captcha code does not match!" />
                                        <div class="cell-3"><input id="captcha_input" name="captcha_input" type="text" required></div>
                                        <div class="cell-6"><label for='message'>Enter the code above :</label><small>Can't read the image? click here to <a href='#' id="rfrshCaptcha">refresh</a></small></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-large main-bg" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" class="btn btn-large" value="Reset" id="reset">
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-5 contact-detalis">
    <div class="padd-vertical-45">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Content End -->

        <!-- Footer start -->
    <footer id="footWrapper">
    <div class="footer-top footer-top-2">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- footer cell 1 start -->
    <div class="cell-2">
    </div>
    <!-- footer cell 1 start -->
    <!-- main menu footer cell start -->
    <div class="cell-3">
    <h3 class="block-head">Main Menu</h3>
    <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product-categories.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/support.html">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="/php/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/site-map/sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- main menu footer cell start -->
    <!-- Useful Links footer cell start -->
    <div class="cell-3">
    <h3 class="block-head">Useful Links</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Useful Links footer cell start -->
    <!-- contact us footer cell start -->
    <div class="cell-3">
    <h3 class="block-head">Keep in Touch</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- contact us footer cell end -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- footer bottom bar start -->
    <div class="footer-bottom">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- footer copyrights left cell -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- footer bottom bar end -->
    </footer>
    <!-- Footer end -->

        <!-- Back to top Link -->
        <div id="to-top" class="main-bg"><span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span></div>

    </div>

    <div class="ModalPopUp">
        <div class="ModalContainer">
            <div class="Modalheader">
                <h3></h3>
                <a href="#" class="closePopup"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ModalContent">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Load JS siles -->      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Waypoints script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION SCRIPTS  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Animate numbers increment -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>

    <!-- slick slider carousel -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Animate numbers increment -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PrettyPhoto script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>

    <!-- Share post plugin script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.sharrre.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Product images zoom plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Input placeholder plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact us js file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/contact.js"></script>

    <!-- Tweeter API plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/twitterfeed.js"></script>

    <!-- Tweeter API plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>

    <!-- NiceScroll plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery cookie script file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/mailChimp.js"></script>

    <!-- Style script file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.style.js"></script>

    <!-- general script file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

    <!-- TopSpot Footer Code - START -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/topspot-footer.js"></script>
    <!-- TopSpot Footer Code - END -->

    <script>

        $('#rfrshCaptcha').click(function(e){
            $.get('refresh.php', function(url) {
                var code = url.split('&&');
                $('#captchaimg').attr('src', code[0]);
            $('#hidCap').val(code[1]);
            });
            e.preventDefault()
            return false;
        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + document.location.protocol + "//www.webtraxs.com/trxscript.php' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the contact_process form:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();


Class ContactClass {

    // override the ip address of the API call.
    private $client_ip;

    function getIP()
    {
      if($this->client_ip) 
      {
          return $this->client_ip;
      }
      elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
      {
          return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      } 
      elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
      {
          return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      }
      else
      {
          return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      }
    }
}

// Initialize class for functions
$contact = new ContactClass();
//echo $contact->getIP();

$site_name = "Test";
if($_POST){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $company=$_POST['company'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email_to = "email@your-domain.com";
        $email_subject = "Contact Us Email from : ".$site_name;
        function died($error) {
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['company']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
            !isset($_POST['message'])) {
            die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
        }
        if( empty($_SESSION['captcha']['code'] ) ||
            strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha']['code'], $_POST['captcha_input']) != 0 ){
            die(' The captcha code does not match! ');
        }
        $name = $_POST['name']; // required
        $company = $_POST['company']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
        $message = $_POST['message']; // required
        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        if(strlen($company) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The company name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        if(strlen($phone) < 7) {
            $error_message .= 'The phone number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        if(strlen($message) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            die($error_message);
        }

        $email_routing =    array(
                           'email1@domain.com',
                             'email2@domain.com',
                             'email3@domain.com',
                             'email4@domain.com',
                             'email5@domain.com',
                             'email6@domain.com'
                        );
        $email_to = $email_routing[$_POST['to']];

        print_r($_POST);
        //die;
        //$email_message = '<html><body><div>';
        $email_message = "Contact us message details below: \n\n";
        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
        $email_message .= 'Senders IP: <a href="http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/'. $contact->getIP() .'">'. $contact->getIP() .'</a>'."\n";

        //$email_message .='</div></body></html>';
        // email header
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@domain.com' ."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        $result=1;

        if($result){
            echo "Thanks ".clean_string($name)." We'll get back to you soon.";
        }
    }

    exit();
}
?>
```

This thing is so screwed up, I'm lost! Thanks so much!

Comment: how are you using/calling the `died()` function? I see `die($error_message);` you may have meant to use `died($error_message);`

Comment: *snore*..... wake me up when you got that ^ unless I'm totally out of the ballpark.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Hi Fred, this is how it was given to me, I'm not a PHP guy so I'm completely lost.

Comment: Hi Riggs, it was all indented nicely but I had to add a ton of indenting so it would all be in a code block.... I apologize.

Comment: Well I managed it, in the time we waited for a responce

Comment: I thought I had seen this code somewhere before

Comment: I know its possible to define functions inside IF's etc but  I cannot say I like the process in the slightest